# Apache on MacOS Sierra: AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for Macbook-Pro.local AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine…

Tags: macos, apache

I updated MacOS Sierra's Apache and PHP, and now whenever I `$ sudo apachectl restart` I get this:

```
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for My-MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to
suppress this message
```

Things I've tried so far that didn't work:

- Setting `ServerName localhost` in /etc/httpd.conf
- Setting `ServerName localhost:80` in /etc/httpd.conf
- Setting `ServerName 127.0.0.1` in /etc/httpd.conf
- Setting `ServerName 127.0.0.1:80` in /etc/httpd.conf
- Ensuring `127.0.0.1       localhost` is set in /etc/hosts
- Repeatedly restarting Apache

Comment: How did you update Apache and PHP and why because usually it's not recommended to modify the **system's** Apache & PHP

Answer (score 16):

When restart the httpd.

Try:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

Don't use:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: It worked, would you explain more why do I use `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart` ?

Comment: It's because you have two different installations of Apache - the one that came with the system and the one you installed yourself.

Comment: Really helpfull for me

Answer (score 4):

The error message you provided gives you the answer:

> Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

So, in your `httpd.conf` file, you need to set the server name by un-commenting and editing the following line

`#ServerName www.example.com:80`

to...

`ServerName www.some-web-server.com`

This should be done in the **main** `httpd.conf` and should be the FDQN (fully qualified domain name) of the server you are running.  Keep in mind that this is for the main server.  You can set individual server names in the `VirtualHost` definitions

For instance, if you called the server - `mywebser.local`, that should be the ServerName.

Personally, what I like to do, even in a home setup is to have a main definition that goes nowhere  and is very restrictive and create virtual hosts in separate directories so each one can be referenced by a different hostname.

Answer (score 4):

As per message:

> Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message.

you need to find your `httpd.conf` Apache configuration file for example by this command:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

<sup>For example: `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`.</sup>

then edit it and uncomment the line with `ServerName` (make sure it has the valid server name). E.g.

```
ServerName localhost
```

Comment: If you read the question, you'll find this is one of the first things I tried, and it didn't work

Comment: It's because you were editing the wrong `httpd.conf`, not in `/etc`, but the one suggested by `apachectl`, which on macOS is usually somewhere in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

It's work!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!.  Please refrain from adding comments in an Answer.  The preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to [your reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)).  Please see the [About] page and also [answer].

Answer (score 0):

1. When restart the httpd, you should check `which apachectl`.
2. Trying restart system apache server by `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`.
3. If you install httpd24 via brew, you should edit your custom apache config.

   Try `open $(brew --prefix)/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf`, edit the `#ServerName www.example.com:80` to `ServerName www.your-server.com:80`.

   Then `sudo apachectl restart` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on macOS High Sierra and the solutions here worked for me.

I edited the config file:

`/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

I uncommented and modified the line starting by `#Servername` with

`Servername localhost:8080`

This resolved the issue for me.